# CSS sibling selector (~) with inverted order

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using CSS sibling selector (~) this way:

```
X:hover ~ Y { }
```

It seems like it works only when X are located before Y (in the HTML).
Can be shown at http://jsfiddle.net/8LFWR/

Placing Y before X makes it stop working.
See http://jsfiddle.net/6WLhe/

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS alone. The `~` combinator only looks in one direction and you can only apply styles to the rightmost element in a selector, so simply placing Y before X won't work.

You'll need to use JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**X ~ Y**

```
ul ~ p {  
   color: red;  
}
```

This sibling combinator is similar to `X + Y`, however, `it’s less strict`. While an adjacent selector (ul + p) will only select the first element that is immediately preceded by the former selector, this one is more generalized. It will select, referring to our example above, any p elements, as long as they follow a ul.

[**the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: 1) Please link to the source whenever you quote something from elsewhere 2) This doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: @BoltClock :http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: Link to it within your answer, not in a comment reply.